# Drawing when not supposed to..?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, drawrect

In my app, I draw a circle on the user's tap and drag. Where they tapped is the center of the circle and as they drag, the radius is up to their finger. Once you draw one circle, if you tap around a couple of times (without dragging), nothing happens but the next time you tap and drag, circles get created (the same sized circles as the last circle made) at each tap you made previously. This doesn't make sense to me because the only things I call on `touchesBegan:withEvent` are

```
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
center = [touch locationInView:self];
```

It should be replacing center each time, but it draws an individual circle at each tap when you finally move your finger.

touchesMoved:

```
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
endPoint = [touch locationInView:self];

distance = (uses center's attributes);

[self setNeedsDisplay];
```

touchesEnded:

```
[self drawBitmap];
```

drawBitmap:

```
if (!CGPointEqualToPoint(center, CGPointZero) && !CGPointEqualToPoint(endPoint, CGPointZero)) {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bounds.size, NO, 0.0);

    if (!incrementalImage) { // first draw;
        UIBezierPath *rectpath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:self.bounds]; // enclosing bitmap by a rectangle defined by another UIBezierPath object
        [[UIColor clearColor] setFill];
        [rectpath fill]; // fill it
    }
    [incrementalImage drawAtPoint:CGPointZero];

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, sW);
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), r, g, b, o);
    CGContextSetLineCap(context, kCGLineCapRound);
    CGRect rectangle = CGRectMake(center.x - distance, center.y - distance, distance * 2, distance * 2);
    CGContextAddEllipseInRect(context, rectangle);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);

    incrementalImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
}
```

drawRect

```
    [incrementalImage drawInRect:rect];

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, sW);
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), r, g, b, o);
    CGContextSetLineCap(context, kCGLineCapRound);
    CGRect rectangle = CGRectMake(center.x - distance, center.y - distance, distance * 2, distance * 2);
    CGContextAddEllipseInRect(context, rectangle);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);
```

Why do circles get made after the taps, but only appear when you drag? Circles should only be drawn when you drag... Right? I'm almost 99% sure the problem is drawBitmap, but i'm not sure what I should do to check if it was only a tap or a drag. Also, if the problem is drawBitmap, why don't I see circles when touchesEnd? It's only on drag events that I see them. **EDIT** to be clear, I don't want circles to be drawn *at all* on single taps, only on drags.

Answer (score 1):

You don't call drawing routines on your own. They have to be called when the system is ready for you do to your drawing -- it signals that it's ready by calling your `drawRect:`. You can run whatever drawing routines you like from there. You indicate to the system that you have something that needs to be drawn as soon as it's ready with `setNeedsDisplay`. That's why `touchesMoved:` is causing circles to be drawn. Add a call to `setNeedsDisplay` in `touchesEnded:` and you should see the results you're looking for.

Comment: Sorry, should have specified this is a UIView subclass that overrides drawRect. Anyways, I edited it to mention that I don't want to draw circles on single taps at all. Shouldn't a single tap ONLY change the value of the center pointer?

Comment: Regardless of your desired results, the fundamental problem is that you can't draw directly from `touchesEnded:`, only in a call stack originating from `drawRect:`, which you do not call directly.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you only have `[self setNeedsDisplay];` in `touchesMoved:`, which means that if you only tap, the view will not redraw. You do not redraw on `touchesEnded:`. So that explains part of the behavior.

As for the rest of it, I would put breakpoints or NSLogs to debug what's really happening.